# how to focus a custom cell in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and rowSelected,I want when user focusout on 4th td the 6th td get focus instead of td 5.

```js
   var rowindex=$("#mycustomizedtable).attr('rowselected);
   
   var row=$("#mycustomizedtable tbody).find('tr')[rowindex];

   var tds=$(row).find('td');

   var colselected=$("#mycustomizedtable).attr('colselected');
                  
  
   console.log(colselected);
```

for example : I get result '4' in console

Now,I want 6td get focus.

I write this but I have not the right answer.

```js
if(colselected==4)
  {
    $(row).find('td').eq(6).focus();
  }
```

How can it be done?

Comment: you mean to say that each `<td>` contains a editable DOM element like `<input type="text"` or something similar?

Comment: @vijayP  Yes that's right.

Comment: Can you add the html? If you want to get 6th `td`, then use `eq(5)` because index start at `0`.

Answer (score 2):

you can refer below code for the help. Here we have added the `focusout` listener to all the `input` elements present in out `<table>` element. We check if `focusout` is happening from 4th cell's `input` or not. And if it is happening from there then we are forcing to focus in 6th cell's `input` box. Hope it will guide you to achieve your goal.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mycustomizedtable td input").focusout(function(){
    var currentElem = $(this);
    var currentIndex = currentElem.closest("td").index();
    if(currentIndex == 3)
      currentElem.closest("tr").find(":nth-child(6)").find("input").focus();
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mycustomizedtable">
  <thead>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Second</th>
    <th>Third</th>
    <th>Fourth</th>
    <th>Fifth</th>
    <th>Sixth</th>
    <th>Seventh</th>
 </thead> 
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="5th value"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="5th value"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
   </tr>  
 </tbody>
</table>
```